# wso2 microintegrator y dashboard. Error: No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login

Tags: php, wso2

Estuve instalando Wso2 MicroIntegrator y Wso2 Mi Dashboard en entorno Linux Debian10 y siguiendo los pasos de la documentación.
Pero cuando intento ingresar como Admin, sale el Error: que no se encuentra MicroIntegrator instalado.
Lo cierto es que MIntegrator sí está corriendo y Dashboard también, inclusive con el código agregado en el archivo deployment.xml dentro de /conf.
No entiendo que está ocurriendo.
Será que se debe configurar algo del lado del Dashboard?
Adjunto capturas. Ojalá alguien pueda ayudar.
Desde ya muchas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido, el código y los mensajes de error deben ir como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los lineamientos del sitio, para que sea mejor recibida y de paso evitar recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: ¿Esto qué tiene que ver con Delphi?